# Expected revenue maximizing auction & ex-post efficiency

Tags: auctions, expected-utility

Is it true that in the design of the expected revenue maximizing auction in the standard independent private value setting, the allocation of the object may be ex-post inefficient?

Comment: Im fairly certain this is true. The optimal auction in this case is a 2nd price auction with a reserve price. The reserve price is inefficient as trade will not always occur.

Answer (score 0):

In the revenue-maximizing auction as defined by Myerson '81 there are two sources of inefficiency. The optimal allocation awards the good to the buyer with the highest virtual value, given this virtual value is non-negative. The virtual value is defined as $\theta_i  - \frac{1-F_i(\theta_i)}{f_i(\theta_i)}$, using the standard notation.

1. The good may not be allocated although trade is efficient. This case cannot occur if the virtual values are always positive. Intuitively, if the lowest possible value weighted by the density at that point is sufficiently high.
2. The good may not be allocated to the agent with the highest value (if the ranking of virtual values and actual values does not coincide). This case cannot occur if all values are drawn from the same distribution.